# MediaPlayer in Storyboard

Tags: xcode4.2, xcode-storyboard, mpmediaplayercontroller

I am trying to get a video file to work within a UIView in storyboard (Xcode 4.2).  I see a lot of examples of pressing a button to activate the video.  Basically I want the opening UIView to have the video at the top half of the screen and then the user taps it begins the video.  Or am I better not doing this in storyboard as I am limiting my self to devices running iOS 5.0 or above.
Regards

amidabrian